# rails overall request time is longer than views+active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this log entry:

`Completed 200 OK in 519ms (Views: 306.2ms | ActiveRecord: 32.8ms)`

How could that happen that the views rendering + active record is lower than the overall request time?

This is the object in action pack which holds the times:

```
=> #<ActiveSupport::Notifications::Event:0x007feeeba29590
 @children=[],
 @duration=742.621,
 @end=2017-02-06 12:23:23 +0200,
 @name="process_action.action_controller",
 @payload=
  {:controller=>"ProjectsController",
   :action=>"update",
   :params=>{"project"=>{"name"=>"Wwww.."}, "client_initiated_at"=>"Mon, 06 Feb 2017 10:23:22 GMT", "controller"=>"projects", "action"=>"update", "id"=>"3"},
   :format=>:js,
   :method=>"PUT",
   :path=>"/workspaces/3",
   :status=>200,
   :view_runtime=>314.45606005598603,
   :db_runtime=>85.04700000000001},
 @time=2017-02-06 12:23:22 +0200,
 @transaction_id="e0dfa141c53a0a641111">
```

In production the situation is worse:
`Completed 200 OK in 3637ms (Views: 56.5ms | ActiveRecord: 79.8ms)`

We are loosing almost 3.5 seconds on every request just because something else is there too...
Any idea where to start debuting the perf lost?

Comment: One controller action in particular or most requests?

Comment: that is a good question. I am preparing to measure the time spent on middlewares. Any idea how?

Something like this: https://github.com/lukeludwig/rack_timer could be a good start.

Comment: Maybe you are using external sources or APIs in your controller? That is not considered neither View nor Active Record.

Comment: A few things I'd look at before middleware: code which instantiates a crap ton of Ruby objects (eg. Model.all in controller), application server contention (eg. too few workers / threads to process request volume), database contention (eg. critical rows/tables getting locked by slow queries / updates)

Comment: thx fylooi of the tips :)

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [Rack-mini-profiler gem](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler). It's pretty well made and gives great insight into what your looking for.

[This is a pretty good tutorial about it](http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/a-new-way-to-understand-your-rails-apps-performance/)